# Leer y asignar valor al resultado de un comando

Tags: linux, shell

tengo el siguiente script

```
nmap_result=$(sudo nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/24)
own_ip=$(ifconfig wlp2s0b1 | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d':' -f2)
temp_mac=$(echo "$nmap_result" | grep "MAC Address:" | awk '{print $3;}') 
temp_ip=$(echo "$nmap_result" | grep "192.168." | awk '{print $5;}' | grep -v "$own_ip")
temp_vendor=$(echo "$nmap_result" | grep "MAC Address:" | awk '{print $4;}')
readarray -t mac <<<"$temp_mac"
readarray -t ip <<<"$temp_ip"
readarray -t vendor <<<"$temp_vendor"
len=${#mac[@]}
for (( i=0; i<${len}; i++ ));
do
echo ${vendor[i]}": "${ip[i]}" - "${mac[i]}
done
```

que al ejecutarlo me da por ejemplo el siguiente resultado

```
(Hon: 192.168.0.1 - 9x:Dx:1x:6x:Bx:Dx
(Mot: 192.168.0.5 - Ex:9x:2x:Dx:8x:Fx
(LG: 192.168.0.7 - Ax:9x:6x:Fx:Fx:Cx
(TCT: 192.168.0.8 - Bx:4x:1x:Ax:Cx:5x
(LG: 192.168.0.11 - Cx:9x:0x:5x:0x:Cx
```

hay alguna manera de numerar y que se le asigne un valor a cada una de las ip

por ejemplo

```
1. (Hon: 192.168.0.1 - 9x:Dx:1x:6x:Bx:Dx
2. (Mot: 192.168.0.5 - Ex:9x:2x:Dx:8x:Fx
3. (LG: 192.168.0.7 - Ax:9x:6x:Fx:Fx:Cx
4. (TCT: 192.168.0.8 - Bx:4x:1x:Ax:Cx:5x
5. (LG: 192.168.0.11 - Cx:9x:0x:5x:0x:Cx
```

y así hacer un menú de selección y al seleccionar un numero hacer una determinada acción

espero haberme explicado

Comment: No sé si entiendo lo que preguntas... Si lo que quieres es que la salida del script presente una lista numerada, puedes usar el mismo índice del bucle: `echo $((i+1))". "${vendor[i]}": "${ip[i]}" - "${mac[i]}`

Answer (score 3):

Desde el momento que estás utilizando un bucle, ¡utiliza la variable!

```
for (( i=0; i<${len}; i++ )); do
   printf "%d. %s: %s - %s\n" $((i+1)) "${vendor[i]}" "${ip[i]}" "${mac[i]}"
done
```

Fíjate que uso `printf` para tener más control sobre lo que escribo.

---

Nótese que tu código es muy optimizable, pues por ejemplo dices:

```
temp_mac=$(echo "$nmap_result" | grep "MAC Address:" | awk '{print $3;}')
```

cuando un simple `awk` ya lo resolvería:

```
temp_mac=$(awk '/MAC Address:/ {print $3}' <<< "$nmap_result")
```

Comment: pero lo que quiero es que al seleccionar un numero me haga una accion, por ejemplo: read -p '    Option: ' OPT
                      if [[ ! $OPT == "1" ]]; then fi
                      case $OPT in

Comment: @GabrielCaltzontzisuarez entonces edita tu pregunta inicial explicando claramente qué quieres hacer. Notifícame después para que pueda revisar mi respuesta.